# 2checkout inline payment 3D secure issue

Tags: inline, 2checkout, 3d-secure

I was implemented inline payment and set Approved URL(return url) in business account with select 'Header Redirect' options, But after 3D secure page not redirected to given return URL with transaction parameters like order number,transaction id etc. because this parameters store in my system. It's working well on sandbox mode but when i have set live mode not return to set return URL.

Any possibility, can i set 3d secure page in inline (iframe). Currently 3d secure page showing on new page.
Please help me, if any one handle same issue.

Thanks in advance,
Rakesh

Answer (score 0):

I would look to see if the issue is present only on IOS devices.
I manage multiple payment systems and just over a month ago, all of them started failing on the redirect. After careful investigation it was proven that it only occurred when using IOS.
The reason is apple released a stealth update that turned off cookies. They are required by the vendor (Worldpay, Protec etc) to hold your data while processing through the 3D secure as it is an Iframe.
Since the data is not saved, although a payment is made successfully (remember 3D secure is to verify cardholder present and not the actual payment) there is no information for the call-back to use and therefore it fails.
This is entirely in the hands of Apple, the banks cannot do anything, the vendors are helpless and the end user is none the wiser.
One has to wonder if this was an intentional move by Apple to undermine other payment processors as this started after the announcement of 'Apple Pay'.
I hope this clarifies things for you